# Laravel: How to create storage link after moving the public directory to root?

Tags: php, laravel, symlink, shared-hosting

I'm trying to deploy a Laravel project using Hostinger shared hosting. I have a subdomain setup that points to the root dir `/blog` & have the Laravel files in `/blog/laravel`.

I moved the contents of public to `/blog` but realized this broke my storage link.

**How can I create a working storage link in the root `/blog` dir?**

I tried using `php artisan storage:link` but it returns `symlink(): No such file or directory`

I tried running symlink but it didnt seem to work.

```
$targetFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/laravel/storage/app/public';
$linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/storage';
symlink($targetFolder, $linkFolder);
```

I also tried using `ln -s` through ssh which seemed to create a linked dir but didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

try to change config for your public disk

```
 config/filesystems.php
```

Comment: Thanks, I set `'root' => __DIR__.'/../../storage'` to just save files to my root path w/o needing a storage link. I guess this solves my needs for now.

Comment: good to know :) accept answer pls